# CTE and Lag query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to achieve a running deductive total, but the problem occurs when I have a zero row.  I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here's a batch of my current results.

```
SuppressionDescription  SuppressionPriority SuppressionPriorityOrder    TotalRecords    RecordsLost RunningTotal
Deceased_Bln    1   1   1376    2   1374
Pivotal Postcode Exclusions 9   2   1376    0   1374
Pivotal 3 Month Decline 11  3   1376    24  1352
Postcode exclusions (Complaints)    12  4   1376    0   1352
Gone Away (from Barcode on returned mail)   15  5   1376    30  1346
Pivotal prospects  with a Do Not Mail flag  16  6   1376    234 1112
Email Suppression File  17  7   1376    7   1135
Opt outs & undeliverables from SMS system   18  8   1376    7   1362
Generic Phone Number Suppression    19  9   1376    245 1124
Exclude if not MR, MRS, MISS, MS, NULL  23  10  1376    0   1131
Total Prospects 9999    11  1376    0   1376
```

With my query, the first two rows calculate.  A total of 1,376 less 2 leaves 1,374 and the second row has no RecordsLost, so the RunningTotal remains the same.  So far so good.

But because Row 2 has a 0 count, it means row 3 (whilst it has a RecordsLost of 24) gets out of sync.

I've tried adding various case statements, to try and get totals for different scenario's, but it never quite works.

Here is my statement:

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT        ID, SuppressionTypeID, ContactMethodType, SupplierName, SuppressionDescription
                    ,           SuppressionCount, TotalRecords, RecordsLost, SuppressionPriority, SuppressionPriorityOrder  
                    ,           CASE WHEN SuppressionPriority = 9999
                                    THEN TotalRecords
                                    ELSE TotalRecords - RecordsLost END AS RowDiff  
                    ,           CASE WHEN RecordsLost = 0
                                    THEN LAG(RecordsLost, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierName, ContactMethodType ORDER BY SuppressionPriorityOrder) 
                                    ELSE RecordsLost END AS RecordsLostRoll
                    FROM        #tmpSup 
                    WHERE       SupplierName        = 'Freeman Grattan Holdings'
                    AND         ContactMethodType   = 'A'
                    )
    SELECT      SuppressionTypeID, ContactMethodType, SupplierName, SuppressionDescription
    ,           SuppressionPriority, SuppressionPriorityOrder
    ,           TotalRecords
    ,           RecordsLost
    ,           CASE WHEN SuppressionPriorityOrder = 1
                    THEN RowDiff 
                    ELSE    (LAG(RowDiff, 1, RowDiff)
                                OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierName, ContactMethodType ORDER BY SuppressionPriorityOrder)) - RecordsLost
                    END AS RunningTotal
    FROM        CTE
    ORDER BY    SupplierName
    ,           ContactMethodType
    ,           SuppressionPriority
```

I'd like to see the RunningTotal as:
1374
1374
1350
1350
1320
1086
1079
1072
827
827
1376 (for total Prospects)

Any suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you create a [sql fiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d88f/6) with the schema for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a 'window frame' in the windowed function to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    SuppressionPriorityOrder,
    TotalRecords,
    RecordsLost,
    TotalRecords - SUM(RecordsLost) OVER 
      (
        PARTITION BY SupplierName, ContactMethodType
        ORDER BY SuppressionPriorityOrder ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING -- this tells the SUM() to add up all preceding records (including the current row)
      ) RunningTotal
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'Freeman Grattan Holdings' AS SupplierName, 'A' AS ContactMethodType, 1 AS SuppressionPriorityOrder, 1376 AS TotalRecords, 2 AS RecordsLost UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Freeman Grattan Holdings' AS SupplierName, 'A' AS ContactMethodType, 2 AS SuppressionPriorityOrder, 1376 AS TotalRecords, 0 AS RecordsLost UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Freeman Grattan Holdings' AS SupplierName, 'A' AS ContactMethodType, 3 AS SuppressionPriorityOrder, 1376 AS TotalRecords, 24 AS RecordsLost UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Freeman Grattan Holdings' AS SupplierName, 'A' AS ContactMethodType, 4 AS SuppressionPriorityOrder, 1376 AS TotalRecords, 0 AS RecordsLost  UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Freeman Grattan Holdings' AS SupplierName, 'A' AS ContactMethodType, 5 AS SuppressionPriorityOrder, 1376 AS TotalRecords, 30 AS RecordsLost
    ) x
```

Reference: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Comment: AHiggins you are a legend :)

Answer (score 0):

I try to simulate the best I could your data. Let me know if you need some changes on the sqlFiddle

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28c74/5)

I use another CTE to calculate the sum of lost records

```
WITH 
    LOST AS (
        SELECT 
            SuppressionPriorityOrder, 
            (SELECT SUM(RecordsLost) 
             FROM tmpSup T2 
             WHERE T2.SuppressionPriorityOrder <= T1.SuppressionPriorityOrder) as TotalLost
       FROM  tmpSup T1  
    )
SELECT 
    T.*, 
    L.TotalLost, 
    CASE WHEN SuppressionPriority = 9999
        THEN T.TotalRecords
        ELSE (T.TotalRecords - L.TotalLost) END AS RunningTotal
FROM  
    tmpSup T INNER JOIN
    LOST L ON T.SuppressionPriorityOrder = L.SuppressionPriorityOrder
```

Comment: Many thanks. First thing Monday, I'll give your code snippet a try